# How to setup Vagrant Windows Server machine with SQL Server on it

Tags: sql-server, windows-server, vagrant

Can anyone explain (or give a link) how to setup MS Windows Server VM using Vagrant on Linux (Arch Linux)? I was searching in Google but only think that I found are instructions how to setup Vagrant on Windows, not how to setup Windows on Vagrant.

Comment: see http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/in-search-of-a-light-weight-windows-vagrant-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Google Groups conversation](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vagrant-up/Ndnu4jIjg3o/BpI3xTnsSgMJ), there aren't any Windows boxes for Vagrant, unfortunately. You would have to just use VirtualBox to run Windows Server if you need SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Windows 7 EE box listed here:

http://www.vagrantbox.es/